# PHP variable to JS with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am having a very tough time transfering a php variable to javascript through json.

I have debugged it throughly and Ive come to the conclusion that something must be wrong with the javascript code. I am saying this because I output the json encoding in my php and see that I get {"result":"4","success":true}, where 4 is the variable value.

But when I try to get the variable in javascript like this:

```
$('#add').on('submit',function(){
var that = $(this), contents = that.serialize;
console.log("after serialize");
$.ajax({
    url: 'caradded.php',
    contentType: 'json',
    data : contents,
    type: 'post',
    success : function(data){

    /*
    try {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(result);
    } catch (e) {
        alert("Output is not valid JSON: " + data);
    }*/


        console.log("result0!! " + data.result);

        console.log("result1!! " + data);



        try{
        localStorage.setItem("storageName",data);
        } catch (e) {
        alert("couldnt set item: " + data);
    }

    }


});
/*


 error: function (request, error) {
    alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
    },

*/
//dataType: 'json',
//data: contents,
//So we do not submit data:
//return false;
// console.log(arguments);
 });
```

then I get the following output on submit (a form submission):

```
result0!! null
result1!! [Object object]
```

The following is my php json encoding:

```
header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode(array(
'result' => $GLOBALS['price'],
'success' => true


  ));


 exit();
```

If I change $GLOBALS['price'] with a string like "test" then it works just fine. Again note that $GLOBALS['price'] outputs a value in my console.

Anyone who has any idea what Im doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Best regards
William.

Comment: Instead of `console.log("result1!! " + data);`, what do you see if you instead use `console.log("result1!!", data);`? (Passing `data` as a second argument lets console output the actual value, instead of trying to turn it into a string and outputting `[Object object]`)

Comment: Or `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`

Comment: It still outputs {result:null,success:true}, unfortunately. But thank you

Comment: Are you sure that $GLOBALS['price'] is set?

Comment: Hundred percent sure, but I think I am on to what might me wrong: I have a html form called form.html and php called carsadded.php, where the input in the form is handled an put into a database. The thing is I have an action="caradded.php" for the form, which makes it go there when clicked, but I also have an event listener for the submit button using jquery. (this is where I handle the json decoding). It seems that maybe it enters the jquery faster than the php file and therefore the variable is only set after the jquery is done and therefore the null value. How could I solve this?

Comment: I am currently trying inline javascript without succes